# What kind of JS module is this

Tags: javascript

I have to make third party js into this format.
What's the name of this kind of module format? AMD? CommonJS?

I also have to convert this 3rd library (https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/dist/axios.js)  in the below format. However, from the dist folder, the JS code has very odd format I could not simply apply it into my expect format like below.

Any idea?

```
export var highcharts = (function() {
  var highcharts = {
    version: "3.5.17"
  };
  ....
  return highcharts;
}).call(window);
```

Comment: looks like a ES6 module - and the link you provided does not link to a file - so, which one do you need to change, all of them seem to use node module pattern

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @Bravo. I need to change this one https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/dist/axios.js into the format I mentioned in the description. Just have no idea what should I do? Should have some converter to do this right? Munal work will kill me for sure

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Are you sure you can’t use a loader plugin of some kind to support how it’s being exported? (As CommonJS, in https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/19969b4fbd6b5b6da67825a69b0f317afa1327dd/lib/axios.js = https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/19969b4fbd6b5b6da67825a69b0f317afa1327dd/index.js .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for sure an es6 module.

The `export var highcharts` part grants it.

The second part is an old yet still working way to define things without any major danger of name clash due to dirty namespace.

It is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), but "applied" to the window object.

[AMD/UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) are another thing, since they tried to detect or at least mimetize other common modules strategies.